# Where is the appropriate place to release a variable w/ an Objective-C switch statement?

Tags: objective-c

In the following code

```
NSDictionary *test;

switch (xxx) {
  case 1:
   ...
   return YES;
   break;

  case 2:
   ...
   return NO;
   break;

  case 3:
   ...
   return YES;
   break;
}

[test release];
```

will the "test" variable be properly released or should there be a separate release statement w/in each switch case statement?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

every time you `return XXX;`, `release` is not called on your object. I suggest to refrain from returning mid-procedure. Better to do something like:

```
BOOL result = NO;
switch (xxx) {
  case 1: ... result = YES; break;
  case 2: ... result = NO; break;
  case 3: ... result = YES; break;
  default: result = NO;
}
[test release];
return result;
```

Answer (score 4):

If you always want test to be released, just use `[test autorelease]` before the switch statement, which will cause release to be called on test sometime after the function returns.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a class' field you should release it in `dealloc` method, else, if it's a local variable (as it seems in your case), you should release it before it gets out of scope (unless, of corse, the method's aim is to return a dynamically allocated variable).

Answer (score 1):

As it is a local scope variable, and as long as you do not leave (`return`) before the end of the `switch` block, it will be ok to release it after the switch statement.

If you do not `alloc` it inside a one of the `case`s statements, it will remain nil and there is no problem with sending `release` messages to a nil element, it is ok to release it after the switch statement.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the good solutions given, you can do this:

```
@try {
    switch(xxx) {
        case 1:
            ...
            return YES;
            break;

        case 2:
            ...
            return NO;
            break;

        case 3:
            ...
            return YES;
            break;
    }
} @finally {
    [test release];
}
```

Finally blocks run even after a return.

The autorelease solution probably looks cleaner, but if for some reason you really don't want to use autorelease you can do this.

Comment: +1 For interesting, but definitely an abuse of the exception handling syntax. :)